# Format Issue while exporting data from SQl server to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a column in Sql server table with datatype of varchar which is shown below in the image

[image]

When i export this column to excel through vb.net codes it is showing as different number data in excel. I tried using this format in code
ws.Cells("D:D").Style.Numberformat.Format = "0"

Comment: How can people help with code problems when you don't post the code?

Comment: Have you tried setting the column as a `text` column? Your column type in DB is (for all intents and purposes) text. BTW, 100% agree with @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: If you use Epplus to generate the Excel file and load the data with eg `LoadFromDataReader` or `LoadFromDataTable`, the output will be a text field.